How to use environment variable in kamailio config file
I am trying to assign environment variable as follows in kamailio.conf
listen=udp:0.0.0.0:5060 advertise $env(MY_IP):5060

Looks like using the environment variable as above is an invalid configuration.
Is there a way to use IP from env var to advertise. Even better, is there a way to use result in a stun query as an advertised address?

Here is a code to use MY_IP environment variable value in config,
# This will create MY_IP define with value from environment variable
#!defenv MY_IP

# MY_IP will be replaced with the value from MY_IP define
listen=udp:0.0.0.0:5060 advertise MY_IP:5060

To dynamically figure out ip address of the current machien one can use following command before starting kamailio
export MY_IP=$(curl -s ifconfig.me)

